# need a way to change "\'S" to " 's " while querying for data in python from mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I only have read access to a table in MySQL and the data contains names with escape characters. the actual data is "John's" but while querying in python through sql, the output is "John'S". "'S" needs to be changed to " 's". I have tried using .str.replace(" ' " ," \' ") to escape the first \ but the result doesn't change.

Comment: included charset = utf8 which solved my issue of reading characters of other languages.. and now "John\'s" instead of "John\'S".. tried again with .str.replace ("'","\'") but same result.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].